# jQuery Validate Plugin w/AJAX Won't Submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

VERY new to jQuery. Attempting to use jQuery Validate plugin. After entering code that I "Frankensteined" together from plugin docs, several posts here, other sites and videos, I am not able to get this to submit. JSHint shows 5 errors, starting with the submitHandler line.

It actually destroyed the layout of my page, so I must have it pretty mucked up. I do have all dependent libraries linked correctly (spinJS, jQuery, jQuery Forms, ), as the rest of the jQuery worked. By "worked" I mean the form would submit to mail script and send email.

After entering validate code page would refresh upon submit.
I was able to see the the "please enter your first name" etc errorContainer overlay, but the form wouldn't submit, but the page was intact. I added a submitHandler and wrecked the whole thing. Hidden, stacked divs are visible.

The form submit DID work prior to adding the validate code.

I'm positive there are errors throughout. Does this look ANYTHING like what I need? Any direction would be GREATLY appreciated.

***This code worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            $( '#submit' ).prop( "disabled", true );
            $('#spinz').spin('daycare','red');      
            $.post("php/mailer.php", $("#contactInput").serialize(),  function(response) {
                $('#spinz').spin(false);    
                $("#contact").hide();
                $("#8Btn").css("color", "#BCDF62");
                $("#confirm").show("slide");
             });
             return false;
         });
    });
</script>
```

**This doesnt

```
<script type="text/javascript">                 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div .contentBox").hide(); // hides all content divs w/class=contentBox
        $("#homePage").show("slide"); // animates home page loading
        $(".linkButtons").css("color", "white"); // turns   all link text to white (not selected)
        $("#1Btn").addClass("menuLit");
        $("#1Btn").css("color", "#BCDF62");
        $("#submit").prop( "disabled", false );

        /*Validation Code*/
        $(function(){
            $('#contactInput').validate({
                rules: {
                    fNameInput: "required",
                    lNameInput: "required",
                    pNumber:        "required",
                    email:          "required",
                    msgArea:    "required"
                },                          
                messages: {
                    fNameInput: "Please enter your first name.",
                    lNameInput: "Please enter your last name.",
                    pNumber:    "Please enter your phone number.",
                    email:        "Please enter your email address.",
                    msgArea:    "Please type a message."
                },
                errorContainer: $('#errorContainer'),
                errorLabelContainer: $('#errorContainer ul'),
                wrapper: 'li'
            });

            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $('#submit').prop( "disabled", true );
                $('#spinz').spin('daycare','red');      
                $.post("php/mailer.php", $("#contactInput").serialize(),    
                    function(response) {
                        $('#spinz').spin(false);    
                        $("#contact").hide();
                        $("#8Btn").css("color", "#BCDF62");
                        $("#confirm").show("slide"); 
                    }       
                });

<script/>
```

Comment: I know you're new to this, but learning how to properly indent/format the code will make it easier to read and troubleshoot for you and us.    Have you checked your console for JavaScript errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be seeing some serious JavaScript errors in your console log.

You've incorrectly placed your `submitHandler` *outside* of the `.validate()` method as well as some misplaced/missing closing brackets.  Simply indenting and formatting your code revealed these mistakes instantly...

```
$('#contactInput').validate({
    rules: {
        ....
    },                          
    messages: {
        ....
    },
    errorContainer: $('#errorContainer'),
    errorLabelContainer: $('#errorContainer ul'),
    wrapper: 'li'
});

submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('#submit').prop( "disabled", true );
    $('#spinz').spin('daycare','red');      
    $.post("php/mailer.php", $("#contactInput").serialize(), function(response) {
        $('#spinz').spin(false);    
        $("#contact").hide();
        $("#8Btn").css("color", "#BCDF62");
        $("#confirm").show("slide"); 
     }   // <- ??    
 }); // <- ??
```

The `submitHandler` belongs *inside* of the `.validate()` method...

```
$('#contactInput').validate({
    rules: {
        ....
    },                          
    messages: {
        ....
    },
    errorContainer: $('#errorContainer'),
    errorLabelContainer: $('#errorContainer ul'),
    wrapper: 'li',
    submitHandler: function() {
        ....
    }
});
```

---

**Side note**:  You've wrapped your `.validate()` method within a `$(function(){...})`.  This is a DOM ready event handler.  The issue with this is that you already have it all within another DOM ready event handler, `$(document).ready(function(){...})`.

`$(function(){...})` is simply shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){...})` so it's pointless to put one inside of the other.

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks for the lesson.